# How do I print to a Bluebird BIP-1300 thermal printer from C#?

Tags: c#, embedded, thermal-printer

My application runs under CF 2.0 locally and i would like to know how to connect and send something to print in the embedded printer of a http://www.milliontech.com/home/content/view/195/95/'>Bluebird BIP-1300 device.

Ideally i would like an example in C#.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this particular device, but in general, printers in this class require you to send RAW data, as they don't have Windows drivers.

[This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) outlines how to send data to the device using C#: whether this is useful for you depends on whether the unmanaged APIs used are available in the environment your CF app runs on.

In case the APIs are supported, what you need next are the correct escape codes for the device in order to get the on-paper results you want. These are usually well-documented in the printer manual.

If the Spooler API is not available, or you run into other issues that make this approach more trouble than it's worth, the third-party [PrinterCE.NetCF SDK](http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE_NetCF.htm) may also be worth looking into.

Answer (score 4):

Use bbpdaapi.dll (search by google)
and in c#

```
using Bluebird.BIP.Printer;
...
this.prn1 = new Bluebird.BIP.Printer.Printer();
if (!this.prn1.Open(0))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can not open Printer", "Printer problem");
            }
this.prn1.PrintText("sdfgidfui", 0);
this.prn1.PrintBitmap(@"\My Documents\sample.bmp", 0);

if (this.prn1.WaitUntilPrintEnd() == 1)
{
MessageBox.Show("No paper in Printer", "Printer problem");
                }
            }
this.prn1.Close();
```

and etc..